# Yeoman vs Symfony

Tags: symfony, gruntjs, yeoman

I just started to learn how to build a webpage with the Symfony2 framework.

I'm used to use Grunt tasks provided by the Yeoman generator, to handle caching, minifying, concatenating etc.

Now I know, that Symfony has his own solutions too, namely: the asset() helper, and Assetic.

From what I know, the yeoman tasks and the Symfony methods seems to be incompatible.

With the symfony `{{ asset('asset-src-path') }}` syntax, the yeoman tasks just won't work.

Should I just throw out the whole yeoman thing, and use the Symfony helper functions and filters?

I would prefer yeoman, I'm used to it and I like preprocessing the assets for the prod. site.

Note: I have to use the assetic() helper so I can work with url rewriting.

Comment: Good question - I guess it depends on your project architecture. In cases where you have a clear delineation between the frontend and backend of you app; for example your frontend is a single-page app using angular, and Symfony2 is your API layer, clearly it makes sense to segregate the app into two projects/components. However I assume this is not the case in your scenario? Interestingly, there is a yeoman generator for Symfony2. Might be worth a look? https://www.npmjs.org/package/generator-symfony

Comment: I checked that, but its assets were given by absolute urls instead of project-relative ones.
So: "/images/asd.png" instead of "{{ asset('images/asd.png') }}".

That's definitely a no-go.

Thanks for the advice anyway! ^^

Comment: Darn :) Well it's an interesting question - and it appears others have pondered similar online. Definitely worth adding a self-answer if you find something that works for you!

Comment: I have an other question similar to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22779809/yeoman-vs-urlrouting
Here I'll most likely post a solution for that specific problem, which is not far away from this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell, there's no easy way to achieve what I wanted.

Luckily, there's no real reason to wrestle with this problem, since - as I mentioned in my question - Symfony has Assetic, which is a great solution.

Note that I did try out a yeoman+symfony solution in a project, which ultimately worked, but I think it really doesn't worth the effort.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Yeoman doesn't do any of the stuff you mention, it's simply a configurable generator. All yeoman does is prompt the developer with a few options and then it just downloads, tweaks than dumps a whole bunch of files to a folder. It's run one time — it's just for scaffolding other tools.

Grunt is a task runner built in Node.js. It's somewhat like yeoman in that it automates repetition but it takes over where yeoman leaves off. Whereas yeoman is run at the start of the project and never run again (generally), grunt is run continuously while you develop. The big difference here is that yeoman's generators and grunts tasks barely touch each other — yeoman isn't built for grunt and vice versa. A yeoman generator may create a nicely configured `Gruntfile.js`, for instance, but it's up to the developer to augment this Gruntfile.js to suit new needs.

Symfony2 is a web framework written in PHP. You can use yeoman to scaffold a Symofny2 app, and Grunt to do certain tasks (although Symfony2 ships with it's own task-runner, Grunt is excellent at front-end still). Symfony2 is a very rich, dynamic constellation of modules that is geared at dealing with HTTP requests and responses (among other things). You can write a yeoman generator that wires Grunt into Symfony2, or you can use Symfony2's console component to run your tasks.

All three are flexible but they are not interchangeable: they are all concerned with different things.

This applies to your linked question: [Yeoman vs UrlRouting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22779809/yeoman-vs-urlrouting)

Comment: Thanks for the long answer! I do know the differences between these tools, I was simply having trouble wiring up my dependencies in the Symfony templates, since somehow I couldn't configure properly the Grunt task generated by Yeoman. Since I'm currently working with Gulp and I'm in the process of reworking my frontend workflow, I'll try to make Symfony and wiredep work together. (I would prefer the hash-named asset solution over Assetic's manual "asset_version" updates.) Also I found this link which could be a solution with grunt: https://github.com/stephenplusplus/grunt-wiredep/issues/108

Comment: Right, you're asking Yeoman + Symfony — not Yeoman vs. Symfony.

Comment: Yeah well thinking back I felt like they didn't really work well together, so I thought the "vs" in the title would be appropriate. :) Now I think it's a bit of an over-exaggeration.

Comment: Sounds good :) I'm mainly nudging you to consider that the quality of a question is sometimes more important than it's answers. Perhaps the title is evocative a certain mindset which is valid but ultimately my answer exists mainly to point out that the question is itself misleading. You're clearly knowledgable so don't take the criticism as a reflection on your capability. We all end up asking a few questions which are fundamentally flawed in premise. I think you have a legitimate question, but neither your question or answer are very illuminating of what you're actually trying to discover.

Comment: I do agree with everything you said. Actually I've gone a long way since this question was posted, and I'm currently developing a toolset - consisting of yeoman generator(s), gulp tasks, javascript modules (browserify), a BEM-like sass convention, etc. -, and once I'm done, I'm gonna properly answer my questions. :)